# Duplicate view results when adding a filter related to field with multiple values?

Tags: entities, views

I have a view to list the Voucher content type. I added a filter: `Configure filter criterion: Content: Voucher codes (field_voucher_code)` NOT EMPTY.

The idea is to show the node only if its field `field_voucher_code` is not empty

The `field_voucher_code` is field which has set the **Number of values to 10** at `admin/structure/types/manage/vouchers/fields/field_voucher_code`

The problem is that the view is duplicating each as many time as values has in its field `field_voucher_code`.

How can I eliminate the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by enabling `Aggregation` or set distinct in Query settings

1. Go to your `View->Advanced->Use Aggregation -> set YES`
2. Next in your field filter criteria chose - Count DISTINCT

One more way -
  1. Go to your `View->Advanced->Query Settings -> check DISTINCT`

Comment: Aggregation didn't work, but I get it working fine with`View->Advanced->Query Settings -> check DISTINCT`. Thanks